# How to activate scroll down button within scrollable <div>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here I have a 70%-height `<div>` and a button w/ script which enables a webpage to scroll to the bottom:

```
<div id="divname" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:75%;">
<p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p>
</div>

<script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("button").click(function() { 
                $("html").animate({ 
                    scrollTop: $( 
                      'html').get(0).scrollHeight 
                }, 300); 
            }); 
        }); 
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="scroll()"><b>Scroll to bottom</b></a>
```

What can I do to make the `<div>` scroll to the bottom by clicking the link button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite abit off,

- Scroll to bottom link needs a handler
- Then the selector is `$("#divname")`

```html
<div id="divname" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:calc(100vh - 40px)">
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.toBottom").click(function() {
      let elm = $("#divname")
      elm.animate({
        scrollTop: elm[0].scrollHeight
      }, 300);
    });
  });
</script>

<a href="#" class="toBottom"><b>&#11015; Scroll to bottom</b></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript instead:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("divname");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```